# Constraint/Guard a type in OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml

Given is a type in order to construct a binary tree:

```
type tree = Leaf of int | Node of int * tree * tree
```

Now assume we want to express via types that a binary tree contains a node with an element zero, i.e., I would like to express something of the following form:

```
let rec p x = match x with 
            | Leaf(y) -> y = 0
            | Node(y,l,r) -> y = 0 || (p l) || (p r)

type zerotree = ZeroTree of t:tree where p(t)
```

That means, whenever I have a tree of type ZeroTree, then I can be sure that the tree contains a node with an element zero, i.e., the predicate `p` holds.

Is something like that expressible in OCaml?

Comment: You want to have a tree type such that it always has a node with the payload of 0? Is this like wanting to have an object with an initializer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer 1: No. What you want is beyond the scope of OCaml type system.

Answer 2: You can define `zerotree` as a completely different type from `tree`.

```
type zerotree = 
  | ZLeaf
  | ZNodeL of int * zerotree * tree
  | ZNodeR of ... (* left for the reader *)
  | ZNodeI of ...
```

`zerotree` is either `ZLeaf`, a leaf with `0`; `ZNodeL`, a node whose left subtree is `zerotree`; `ZNodeR`, a node whose right subtree is `zerotree`; or `ZNodeI`, a node whose int is `0`.

Answer 3: Answer 2 only works for some simple data structures and simple invariants. In the real world we often use *private types* to enforce the invariants by forbid arbitrary construction of values:

```
module Z : sig
  type zerotree = private Leaf of int | Node of int * zerotree * zerotree
  val leaf : int -> zerotree
  val node : int -> zerotree -> zerotree -> zerotree
end = struct
  type zerotree = Leaf of int | Node of int * zerotree * zerotree
  let rec p = function
    | Leaf y -> y = 0
    | Node(y,l,r) -> y = 0 || p l || p r
  let check zt = if p zt then zt else assert false
  let leaf i = check (Leaf i)
  let node i l r = check (Node (i,l,r))
end

open Z

(* let z = Leaf 1    Compile error: Cannot create values of the private type *)
(* let z = leaf 1    Runtime error *)
let z = leaf 0
let () = match z with  (* you can still pattern match *)
  | Leaf 0 -> ()
  | _ -> assert false
```

Type `zerotree` is as same as `tree` but its constructors are private outside of module `Z`: you cannot use the constructors to create values but only deconstruct (i.e. pattern match) them outside of the module.

Construction of the value `zerotree` must be done via the functions `Z.leaf` and `Z.node`, which check the property you have to provide.

Comment: I like answer 3). It reminds me of the factory pattern from OOP. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

A hybrid solution is possible but it's clunky. Here we keep a boolean around so we can cheaply convert from a zero-tree to a regular one.

```
type ('left, 'right) either = Left of 'left | Right of 'right

module type Zero_tree = sig
  type t = private Leaf of int | Node of bool * int * t * t
    (* The type of any tree. The boolean indicates whether
       this is a zero-tree.
       The type is private so we can guarantee that the
       boolean is set correctly.
    *)

  type z
    (* The type of zero-trees, a subtype of t which is guaranteed to contain
       at least one zero-node.
       In the module implementation, it uses the same representation as t.
    *)

  (* Constructors *)
  val leaf : int -> t
  val node : int -> t -> t -> t

  val leaf_zero : t
  val node_zero : t -> t -> z
  val node_left : int -> z -> t -> z
  val node_right : int -> t -> z -> z
  val node2 : int -> z -> z -> z

  (* Destructors *)
  val view : z -> t
  val classify : t -> (z, t) either
  val as_zero : t -> z option
end

module Zero_tree : Zero_tree = struct
  type t = Leaf of int | Node of bool * int * t * t
  type z = t

  let leaf n = Leaf n
  let leaf_zero = Leaf 0

  let is_zero = function
    | Leaf 0
    | Node (true, _, _, _) -> true
    | _ -> false

  let node n a b =
    let iz = n = 0 || is_zero a || is_zero b in
    Node (iz, n, a, b)

  let node_zero a b = node 0 a b
  let node_left = node
  let node_right = node
  let node2 = node

  let view x = x

  let classify x =
    if is_zero x then Left x
    else Right x

  let as_zero x =
    if is_zero x then Some x
    else None
end
```